# C xor encryption alternatives

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption

I was wondering about some other valid alternative to the XOR Bit-Level
encryption algorithm.

well last night i wrote my question in a kind of hurry so what I was really meaning was to find out what other alternatives are out there beside the XOR to keep some sort of basic encryption, as far as I was thinking I was considering a bit swapping following a simple rule like a math formula with a key or so.

Comment: xor is as close to "zero" computational complexity as you're going to get. Could you explain further?

Comment: Other than that, it also gets you as close to zero security as you're going to get.

Comment: [Caesar's cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar%27s_cipher)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xor eax, eax` is actually used to substitute `mov eax, 0` in assembly (because it has same speed and is shorter in bytecode). So, if XOR is as fast as MOV, there is practically no such thing that has "lower computational complexity" than XOR and does similar thing (in terms of this question).

Comment: Good answer, but wrong explanation. The reason `xor eax, eax` is used instead of `mov eax, 0` is that is it recognized as an instruction that doesn't have a dependency on `eax`, in practice, as if it was not a `xor` at all. In the Pentium Pro, `xor eax, eax` was treated as a normal `xor`, and Intel's manuals recommended writing/generating `mov eax, 0` for speed.

Comment: Well, they are almost same in terms of speed (it wouldn't be used, if `xor` took too much time - it's assembly, it requires speed!) and `xor eax, eax` is encoded in lower number of bytes - and that's what I've written in my answer.